# EC2 Rails Git Issues: First Push Worked, but Nothing Is Updating Now

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I currently have a remote to an EC2 instance set up on on my local git repo. The push works.

```
git push remote_name master
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
Writing objects: 100% (12/12), 896 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 12 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)
To user_name@dns:eko_web.git
4342c41..7bbc7db  master -> master
```

When I ssh into the remote EC2 I can find the very first push I made copied over my app to var/app/current/ but no further updates. When I look in my bare git repo I find my most recent pushes when I do `git show HEAD:<some_file>`. When I manually edit the view in var/app/current the change isn't reflected in my website; the same initial push is all I see. I have a hook set-up in the post-receive of the bare git repo that is the following:

```
#!bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/app/current git checkout -f
```

As a broad overview, I used the following tutorials to get me this far. http://myrailslearnings.wordpress.com/2013/02/19/getting-ec2-to-use-git-for-rails-app/ http://www.lovholm.net/2013/06/26/push-your-code-onto-your-ec2-instance-with-git/

Thanks for any thoughts on this!

Edit:

Per Rico's suggestion, I started a new instance that hadn't been initialized with Beanstalk. I now have a git repo on the instance that (when updated manually) reflects changes on the server. But I'm still having problems pushing remotely to that location; it shows a successful push but then the files are there but not committed. If I commit them manually and then restart the server the website is updated.

Comment: Is the git repo on your server a bare repo? bare repos don't hold files and just hold commit history so it cannot be used as a working tree. You should git clone on the server. It seem you are re-inventing the wheel. The Rails world has a standard for deploying code: look at https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano

Comment: Yes, the git repo is bare. But the var/app/current is not and does hold a complete version of my app; just from the first push. There's so much to learn that I'm trying not to overwhelm myself with AWS (only used Heroku before) and a deployment tool atm. If I git clone into the server then would I set GIT_WORK_TREE to that location? I don't see how it's actually updating the website itself though...and why did it work the first time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you can do the deployment.  Deploying by pushing directly to a non-bare git repo can be done but it's not that common. (Like http://www.lovholm.net/2013/06/26/push-your-code-onto-your-ec2-instance-with-git/ describes) There are things that you have to watch for. For example you cannot push to a remote repository branch if that branch happens to be checked out.

From the looks of it you were deploying through Elastic Beanstalk initially or something because /var/app/current is the default location where it deploys Rails apps (when you do a git aws.push)  Keep in mind that in a regular Elastic Beanstalk deployment /var/app/current doesn't hold a git repo. It's just a copy of your code (The git repo is saved somewhere else, I believe in S3)

The most common way of deploying from git is to have your git repo in github, bitbucket or a git repository in the cloud. Let's say you use github. At deploy time you would push to the github repository and then the new code gets deployed by cloning or pulling from the github repository into your cloud server. Capistrano is one of the tools that automates this process.

Another way of deploying is pushing to a bare git repository in the same say EC2 server where you are deploying and then pull/clone from that bare repository into another non-bare repository in the same server.

In your case you can also try switching your remote repository to non-bare if you want to see the code there. Easiest way I guess is deleting your bare repository and then cloning the original as a non-bare repository and sticking it where you want to deploy your code.

Comment: Thanks for being so thorough! I think I'm missing a truly basic concept here; if you could fill in the gap or misunderstanding it'd be great. The EC2 exists. It's basically a computer in the cloud. When we speak of deploying by pulling down from github into the cloud server is the cloud server the EC2 instance? The second potential solution you mentioned of pulling/cloning from the bare into a non-bare makes sense. My confusion at this point is how the EC2 knows a specific repo is the one that should be put online and where that's configured.

Comment: To answer your question, yes. The EC2 instance knows about the remote git repository by its git configuration. You can see it with `git config -l`. Or you can look at the content of `.git/config`. It might help if you read up on the basics of pushing and pulling from git. http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes.

Comment: I've read that page several times; maybe I'm not expressing my confusion clearly or I'm misunderstanding. If I push to a github repo on the EC2 how is that EC2 pushing it automatically up to the web when I haven't told it to? Don't I have to tell the EC2 where my app is being stored, store it in a specific place, or do a push from that instance to another remote that will push it? The remote page made sense, but local repo -> ec2 repo -> web has me confused in terms of the implementation on the last step.

Comment: it's saying I need 20 rep, which you just got me, but doesn't seem to be seen in the chat

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46389/discussion-between-rico-and-morgan)